# Generate random RNA transcripts with ending condition

Tags: python, random, dna-sequence

I am trying to write a program that generates random RNA transcripts:
all 4 RNA nucleotides are of equal probability, each sequence begins with a start codon, ends only when a stop codon is introduced.

```
import random

def random_rna():
    rna = 'AUG'
    stop_codon = ['UAG','UAA','UGA']
    while rna[-3:] not in stop_codon:
            rna += (random.choice('AUCG'))*3
    return rna

random_rna()
```

it does not generate a sequence and python is not presenting any errors...

Comment: Your code runs into an infinite loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs into an infinite loop, because `(random.choice('AUCG'))*3` doesn't do what you think it does... see:

```
In [2]: (random.choice('AUCG')) * 3
Out[2]: 'GGG'
```

Rather than call the function thrice, it calls it once and triplicates the result. As a result of this, the `while` condition is never true.

I'd recommend appending to a list, and then joining once at the end. It's cheaper than all the string concatenation calls you make.

```
stop_codon = ['UAG','UAA','UGA']

def random_rna():
    rna = ['AUG']
    while rna[-1] not in stop_codon:
            rna.append(''.join([random.choice('AUCG') for _ in range(3)]))

    return ''.join(rna)

print(random_rna())
'AUGAGCAGCGAGAGGGGCGCGCAGACGACGCCUGGCUCGUAUAGUUAUAGGACCUUCCGUGAACAUAACGCUACAGUCAGGUUGCAAAAUAAGCAGGUAACUAACUAUCUGCAGGCUCGAGUUGUCCUGCCGUAG'
```